# Python regex to replace leading and trailing quotes

Tags: python, regex

How can I replace leading and trailing arbitrary quote strings separately with arbitrary strings using python regex?

**Sample Input String**

```
This is a "quote" and here's another "quote"
```

or

```
This is a &ldquo;quote&rdquo" and here's another &ldquo;quote&rdquo;
```

**Sample Output Strings**

```
This is a &ldquo;quote&rdquo; and here's another &ldquo;quote&rdquo;
```

or

```
This is a <span>"quote"</span> and here's another <span>"quote"</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant of the answer that handles arbitrary quote pairs and converts them into "text", i.e. output 2—all with a single call to `re.sub`:

```
quotes = [('"', '"'), ("&ldquot;", "&rdquot;")]
left = '|'.join(re.escape(t[0]) for t in quotes)
right = '|'.join(re.escape(t[1]) for t in quotes)
regex = r'((%s)(.*?)(%s))' % (left, right)
outstr = re.sub(regex, r'<span>"\3"</span>', instr)
```

To test input strings:

```
>>> replace = lambda x: re.sub(regex, r'<span>"\3"</span>', x)
>>> replace('''This is a "quote" and here's another "quote"''')
'This is a <span>"quote"</span> and here\'s another <span>"quote"</span>'
>>> replace('''This is a &ldquot;quote&rdquot; and here's another &ldquot;quote&rdquot;''')
'This is a <span>"quote"</span> and here\'s another <span>"quote"</span>'
```

Comment: adjusted question to reflect need for arbitrary input/output quote strings

Comment: Sorry, I no longer understand the updated question. The inputs and outputs don't even appear to match.

Comment: look at my non-regex answer which works but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution

Comment: @mogga I've now updated the answer to handle different input quotes with a single `re.sub`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following non-regex solution but there may be a better way?

```
def replace_quotes(value, leadqt='"', tailqt='"', leadrep='<span>', tailrep='</span>', inc=True):
    while leadqt in value:
        value = value.replace(leadqt, leadrep, 1).replace(tailqt,tailrep,1)
    if inc:
        value = value.replace(leadrep, '%s%s' % (leadrep, leadqt)).replace(tailrep, '%s%s' % (tailqt, tailrep))
    return value
```

test it...

```
>>> MYSTR = "This is a \"quote\" and here's another \"quote\""
>>> replace_quotes(MYSTR)
u'This is a <span>"quote"</span> and here\'s another <span>"quote"</span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with nested quotes, but:

```
s = 'This is a "quote" and here\'s another "quote"'
re.sub(r'"(.*?)"', r'<span>\1</span>', s)
# "This is a <span>quote</span> and here's another <span>quote</span>"
```

And then wrap that something like:

```
def rep_quote(s, begin, end):
    return re.sub(r'"(.*?)"', r'{}\1{}'.format(re.escape(begin), re.escape(end)), s)
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I do note that the answer doesn't handle the alternative quotes of the edited question...

Comment: @user4815162342 That would be fair enough - but I can hardly be expected to keep answers up to date with changed questions. Oh well, guess I'll live...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
>>> st='''This is a "quote" and here's another "quote"'''
>>> words=re.findall(r'"\w+"',st)
>>> for x in set(words):
...     st=st.replace(x,'<span>'+x+'</span>')
... 

>>> print st
This is a <span>"quote"</span> and here's another <span>"quote"</span>
```

Comment: I adjusted the question to reflect the need for arbitrary input/output